# Создание интернет магазина внутриигровых предметов

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Хотим создать маленький интернет магазин с внутриигровыми предметами для игры. Пока остановились на Wordpress с плагином Woocommerce.
Как возможно реализовать что после оплаты будет проходить запись в бд с этой покупкой? Возможно вы посоветуете варианты по-лучше.

Comment: WooCommerce всегда пишет в базу состояние заказа.

Comment: Это да, но при этом нам нужно чтобы при покупке отправлялся еще одна запись в бд, но в другую которая привязана к игре. Дабы доставить игроку предмет.

Comment: И какие проблемы использовать хук при покупке и в нем писать в БД что хотите

Comment: Был бы очень признателен если бы рассказали бы об этом подробнее или скинули бы ресурс где почитать, ибо я в вэбе полный профан. Спасибо.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/ - главный источник на русском. https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html - хуки WooCommerce. Вам нужен `woocommerce_order_status_completed`